# Apache kafka with apache Avro

Tags: apache-kafka, schema, avro, confluent-platform

Can someone tel how exactly we can use the Apache Kafka with Apache Avro.It seems, only the Confluent Platform does support schema registry.

Our requirement is to use schema registry without being used the commercial product like Confluent

Answer (score 2):

Another option is the open source Karapace schema registry, designed to be compatible with Confluent's Schema Registry, but an open source project and it supports Avro. https://github.com/aiven/karapace (disclaimer, I work for Aiven and contribute to this open source project)

Comment: I'll update my answer, I wasn't sure what the etiquette would be on being a walking advert for my employer but I appreciate the hint :) The question exactly asks for a registry though, doesn't it? "Our requirement is to use schema registry without being used the commercial product like Confluent"

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a Schema Registry to use Avro. You can define your own Serializer functions to convert between Avro and bytes, and just use that

Otherwise, Confluent's Schema Registry is ["royalty free", not commercialized](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/LICENSE-ConfluentCommunity), the main 5 thing you can't do is to offer it as a public API to compete with Confluent Cloud, but there are other similar projects like Apicurio or Hortonwork's Registry that can be found on Github and Apache 2.0 Licensed